# Transferencia de archivos con sockets en python

Tags: python, socket, tcp

buenos días, soy un poco inútil en estoy del python y estoy intentando aprender, así que perdón de antemano si la duda es muy absurda; tengo que hacer un programa para clase que sea capaz de transferir archivos a través de sockets TCP multihilos.

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import os

# Creamos la función que irá dentro del hilo
def hilo(cliente):
    # Ahora lo primero que tenemos que hacer es leer que es lo que quiere el cliente. Leemos el 'link'
    peticion = cliente.recv(1024).decode('UTF-8').split('\n')

    # En la lista "peticion", tenemos:
    # · en la posición 0 el GET
    # · en la posición 1 qué queremos
    # · en la última posición tenemos el protocolo

    ficheroSolicitado = peticion[0].split()[1]
    fichero = ficheroSolicitado[1:]

    # Comprobamos si el archivo al que intentamos acceder existe:
    if os.path.isfile(fichero):
        cliente.send('EXISTE ILLO'.encode('UTF-8'))

        # Abrimos el archivo que queremos enviar
        with open(fichero, 'rb') as f:
            bytesToSend = f.read(1024)


            cliente.send(bytesToSend)

            # En caso de que no nos lleguen los 1024 para enviar el mensaje:
            while bytesToSend != '':
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                cliente.send(bytesToSend)

    else:
        print('error')

    cliente.close()

def main():
    '''
    Crearemos un servidor web a partir del TCP multihilo hecho en el tutorial
    '''
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Formato ServidorTCP <puerto>")
        sys.exit()

    try:

        port = int(sys.argv[1])
        ip = "192.168.0.24"

        # Creamos el socket del servidor TCP:
        socketServidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # Lo vinculamos al puerto con la función bind()
        socketServidor.bind((ip, port))

        # Establecemos un *timeout*
        socketServidor.settimeout(60)

        # Ponemos el servidor en modo escucha:
        socketServidor.listen()

        # Creamos un bucle infinito
        while True:
            # Recibimos la petición
            socketCliente, address = socketServidor.accept()

            threading.Thread(target = hilo, args = (socketCliente,)).start()


    # Controlamos la excepción por timeout y cualquier otra excepción posible
    except socket.timeout:
        print("60 segundos sin recibir nada.")

    except:
        print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise



    # Cerramos el socket:
    finally:
        socketServidor.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Todo aquello que está dentro de la función "main", sé que me funciona, ya que lo he probado para conectar dos máquinas y enviar un print, entonces, perfecto. En la función de arriba, hilo, la que llama el threading.Thread, es donde creo que está el fallo, las primeras líneas simplemente ven cual es el archivo deseado (también sé que funciona porque lo he probado), y el "with open(fichero, 'rb') as f... sé que se lleva ejecutar, pero no soy capaz de ver ningún archivo. Para llamar al servidor, utilizo el navegador (de ahí la descomposición del link), pero no sé que tengo que hacer para que se pueda ver/descargar el archivo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Diego.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes en la práctica un ciclo infinito por culpa de la línea:

```
while bytesToSend != '':
```

**`bytesToSend` es una variable asociada a objetos de tipo `bytes` mientras que '' es un literal de cadena vacía (tipo `str`)**. Aunque tanto la cadena de bytes como la cadena creada mediante el literal estén vacías, siempre van a ser diferentes porque son objetos de distinta clase.

La comparación correcta sería en todo caso:

```
while bytesToSend != b'':
```

pero esta no es la forma correcta de hacerlo en Python, para empezar creamos un objeto bytes vacío para compararlo con otro... Dado que una cadena de bytes o cualquier otro contenedor (`list`, `str`, `dict`, `set`, etc) es evaluado como `False` si está vacío, basta con hacer:

```
while bytesToSend:
```